# JQuery Which Form Was Submitted

Tags: jquery, forms, submit

I'd like to be able to detect which form on a page was submitted, grab its ID and assign it to a variable. How can I do this?

Thank you!

Comment: `<input type="hidden" name="formName" value="myForm123"/>`

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair: You can have multiple forms, just not nested forms.

Comment: @Rocket thanks for clarification... Mixed sth up :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're working with jQuery. You can easily do this:

```
<form id="form1" ...>
  ...
  <input type="submit" />
</form>

<form id="form2" ...>
  ...
  <input type="submit" />
</form>

<script>
  $('form').submit(function(){
    var form_id = $(this).attr('id'); //here you grab the id
    alert('form '+form_id+' was submitted!');

    return false; //prevent from 'really' submitting
  });
</script>
```

Note that this variable will only be available within that JavaScript-code and only until the page is left/reloaded. If you want to save it permanently, you could e.g. [post it](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) to the server and then save it to the session / a database / a cookie / whatever.